# Trabajando con listas python

Tags: python, python-2.7

tengo la siguiente lista

```
lista=[('1', '3', 0.29), ('1', '2', 0.36), ('1', '5', 0.32),
       ('1', '7', 0.19), ('0', '2', 0.26), ('0', '4', 0.38),
       ('0', '7', 0.16), ('0', '6', 0.58), ('3', '2', 0.17),
       ('3', '6', 0.52), ('2', '7', 0.34), ('2', '6', 0.4),
       ('5', '4', 0.35), ('5', '7', 0.28), ('4', '7', 0.37),
       ('4', '6', 0.93)]
```

Necesito hallar una forma de que las sublistas que tengan '1''s me entreguen los valores del otro numero entero de la lista. es decir 
debo conseguir los datos '3', '2', '5', '7'

gracias

Comment: siempre están en ese orden (id, int, float)?

Comment: helperino, tengo dos preguntas. La primera, ¿en que formato debe ser la salida? (lista, generador, etc), y la segunda pregunta es, ¿todas las tuplas en la lista tienen la misma configuracion (int, int, float)?

Answer (score 13):

No lo especificas, pero si el entero a retornar está siempre en la segunda posición con un simple `for` para ir obteniendo cada tupla y un condicional  para ver si el primer elemento es '1' basta. Usando compresion de listas:

```
lista=[('1', '3', 0.29), ('1', '2', 0.36), ('1', '5', 0.32),
       ('1', '7', 0.19), ('0', '2', 0.26), ('0', '4', 0.38),
       ('0', '7', 0.16), ('0', '6', 0.58), ('3', '2', 0.17),
       ('3', '6', 0.52), ('2', '7', 0.34), ('2', '6', 0.4),
       ('5', '4', 0.35), ('5', '7', 0.28), ('4', '7', 0.37),
       ('4', '6', 0.93)]

res = [tupla[1] for tupla in lista if tupla[0] == '1']
print(res)
```

Las listas/iteradores/sets por compresión son más eficientes, de todas formas si no te sientes cómo con ellas, lo anterior equivale a :

```
res = []
for tupla in lista:
    if tupla[0] == '1':
        res.append(tupla[1])
print(res)
```

Con esto obtienes una lista como salida, la idea es la misma si quieres obtener un iterador, un conjunto o simplemente imprimir la salida sin almacenarla.

**Salida:**

> ['3', '2', '5', '7']

Answer (score 2):

Simplemente porque sí ... lo mismo pero "funcional"

```
result = map(lambda x: x[1], filter(lambda x: x[0] == '1', lista))
```

Si estás en Python 3, eso devuelve un "generator", así que si necesitas una lista

```
result = list(map(lambda x: x[1], filter(lambda x: x[0] == '1', lista)))
```